# RoboRealm for TurtleBot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have anyone tried using RoboRealm for TurtleBot? From their website it is not clear whether RoboRealm is compatible with ROS or not. Also how does it compare with OpenCV and does it worth buying? Any opinions are welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59845/roborealm-for-turtlebot/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used RoboRealm with a Windows XP set up. It is more Windows friendly and may not work on a Linux Distribution. Also, in my opinion you can get most of the functionality of RoboRealm using various packages at ROS, so I will suggest that it may not be worth a buy. However, if you want to get some basic idea of robot vision in the Windows environment then it may be worth a try, it is a good software just that ROS is much better !

Also, consider having a look here, http://answers.ros.org/question/10379/how-can-i-use-roborealm-software-vision-for-machines-in-ros/.

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-04-17**:
well, after trying the trial version, RoboRealm seems very easy to use and to program. It also avoids the dependency problem and other sort of crash that often occurs in ROS.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-04-21**:
@Chik Does RoboRealm has a Ubuntu installer ? You may consider making it work with ROS ! though I doubt if anyone has attempted such !

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-05-06**:
@Chik - I used RoboRealm before switching to OpenCV/ROS and I think it is a fantastic piece of software.  It not only has a ton of vision modules, it also has plugins for many robot controllers.  If you can use Windows and need to get a robot up and running ASAP, it would be my first choice.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-05-06**:
@Chik - RoboRealm does not run natively under Ubuntu or Linux in general.  However, some people have made it work to varying degrees using Wine (Windows emulator for Linux).  See http://www.roborealm.com/forum.php?q=ubuntu&page=0.